# USB Tether keeps repeating 'Checking phone status...'

Tags: wireless, usb, android, tethering, reverse-tethering

I am attempting to use the wireless capability of my Asus Memo Pad HD 7 ME173x tablet as an access point for my Ubuntu PC over USB. I installed USB Tether on both my tablet and my computer. I activate the program on the tablet and it seems to work fine. But running the program on my computer, it keeps repeating `Checking phone status...`, and I can't seem to get a connection.

I found the site http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941773 and followed the steps. So indeed, I installed `libssl-dev` and ran `./configure`, `make` and `sudo ./run.sh`. Unfortunately, USB Tether still keeps repeating `Checking phone status...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the program `USB Tethering` from `Duck Software` does work. It's just as easy as `USB Tether`, but it worked immediately. It enables the USB tethering option in Android, which was removed from this particular version on the Asus Memo Pad HD 7 ME173x tablet.